# Can I access Shape points in Action Script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

We have a Shape (like a cloud) drawn in Flash Professional.
And we want to move shape coordinates in Action Script 3.
The idea is to shake the points a little randomly to create an illusion of motion.
Like a trembling.

By "points" I mean vertexes comprising the Shape, NOT rasterized pixels.

Is it possible in Action Script 3?

If not - what is the easiest way to export Shape points coordinates out of Flash Professional to some simple format (XML)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get such "points" for Shape, but it's possible with BitmapData. There are 3 options for choosing:

1. You can create such an effect by getPixel() and setPixel() if you want to do it from the core
2. Use BitmapData.pixelDissolve() to achieve it.
3. And at last the most simple way is learning TransitionManager(fl.transitions).

Comment: Thanks, but by "points" I mean vertices comprising the Shape, NOT rasterized pixels. As far as I understand you are referring raster graphics and pixels.